# How do I rescind an edit review?

Tags: support

I accidentally approved 
https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5786 . Can I cancel or rescind that action somehow?

First, I did not even get a chance to look at it before my hand slipped. I have no opinion on its merits. Second, I do not care to form an opinion as I no longer participate on this site, and do not want to give the impression otherwise.

Comment: If an edit is incorrect, you can roll it back.

Comment: @AmericanLuke If I rollback, won't the author of the proposed edit need to re-submit it?

Comment: Well if the edit should be there, then don't roll it back. You can roll an edit back, but you can't roll a review back.

Comment: It looks like someone else approved it as well, so I will let it stand.

Answer (score 3):

You can't undo a review. You can however roll back an edit, if you have enough reputation to do so.

The proposer of the edit can, if (s)he want to, resubmit the edit. Presumably (s)he would not do that unless you explained what happened, though, as (s)he would otherwise think that the edit had been rejected.